# Date conversion from POSIXct to Date in R

Tags: r, datetime

can anyone tell me why R give such outcome below:

```
> as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 08:00")
[1] "2013-01-01 08:00:00 HKT"
> as.Date(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 08:00"))
[1] "2013-01-01"
> as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 07:00")
[1] "2013-01-01 07:00:00 HKT"
> as.Date(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 07:00"))
[1] "2012-12-31"
```

Shouldn't it be `2013-01-01` after converting `POSIXct` to `Date` for `2013-01-01 07:00`, is there any way to change the cutoff from `08:00` to `00:00`?

#### Update #1

I found the following can fix my problem, but in a less neat way

```
> as.Date(as.character(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 07:00")))
[1] "2013-01-01"
```

Comment: There is a similar question and answers here that may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62743019/wrong-date-when-converting-posixct-date-time-to-date-timezone-not-fixing-it/62743807#62743807

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The problem here is timezones - you can see you're in `"HKT"`. Try:

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 07:00", 'GMT'))
[1] "2013-01-01"
```

From `?as.Date()`:

> ["`POSIXct`" is] converted to days by ignoring the time after midnight
>   in the representation of the time in specified timezone, default UTC

Answer (score 36):

Use the time zone parameter of `as.Date`:

```
as.Date(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 07:00",tz="Hongkong"))
#[1] "2012-12-31"

as.Date(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 07:00",tz="Hongkong"),tz="Hongkong")
#[1] "2013-01-01"
```

In fact, I recommend always using the `tz` parameter when using date-time converting functions. There are other nasty surprises, e.g. with daylight saving time.

Comment: Worth mentioning after hinting at the daylight saving one, that sometimes you need to put tz="" to get it to work properly.  I don't really know why, I just avoid `POSIXct` at all costs.

Comment: This is the best answer (And should get the green tick) as it is more thorough and precise regarding the tz argument applied in date (NOT `as.POSIXct`), not the green ticked answer by the OP.

Answer (score 4):

This happens as documented and previously explained when contemporaneous UTC time is before (your third example) or after midnight on your POSIXct date. To see the math for yourself, inspect `as.Date.POSIXct` at the console. The math under the default `tz="UTC"` is clear. In the non-default case, R essentially calls `as.Date.POSIXlt`, and the `date-travel` does not occur. In fact, if you had started with the `lt` object you would not have had this problem:

```
> as.Date(as.POSIXlt("2013-01-01 07:00", tz = "Hongkong"))  
[1] "2013-01-01"
```

The easiest work-around is to call as.Date with `tz=""` to force using the less offending `as.Date.POSIXlt` algorithm:

```
> as.Date(as.POSIXct("2013-01-01 07:00"), tz = "")  
[1] "2013-01-01"
```

Comment: I need to correct myself. tz="" does not always work. If you never want to change the timezone of your POSIXct object, x, go straight to POSIXlt first, then to Date:  
as.Date(as.POSIXlt(x))