# How to extract correct date from POSIXct element?

Tags: r, posix, posixct, as.date

How can I get the correct date from the first column in my code?

```
test <- data.frame(posixdate = c("2013-05-01 00:59:00", "2013-05-01 01:59:00", "2013-05-01 02:59:00", "2013-05-01 03:59:00"))
test$posixdate <- as.POSIXct(test$posixdate, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )
test$date <- as.Date(test$posixdate)
```

The above code results in:

```
  posixdate           date
1 2013-05-01 00:59:00 2013-04-30
2 2013-05-01 01:59:00 2013-04-30
3 2013-05-01 02:59:00 2013-05-01
4 2013-05-01 03:59:00 2013-05-01
```

The first two dates are not correct. What did I do wrong?
If `as.Date()` is not the right function, how could I get the date (without hours, minutes, seconds) alternatively?

Comment: You probably have daylight saving issues. You''ll need to specify your timezone for both, for example `test$posixdate <- as.POSIXct(test$posixdate, tz = "GMT") ; as.Date(test$posixdate, tz = "GMT")`

Comment: Thank you! I suppose "CET" does not automatically consider daylight-saving periods?

Comment: `as.Date` ignores it. Just do `test$posixdate <- as.POSIXct(test$posixdate, tz = "CET") ; as.Date(test$posixdate, tz = "CET")`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. If you posted your solution as an answer I could accept it.

Comment: This is a duplicate and already has an answer in previous questions so no need to post another similar solution. Though, I admit this is a hard thing to understand by your own for a new R user thus I've upvoted your question.

Comment: One last question: Does as.POSIXct() use local (system) time zone if not otherwise given (tz="") while as.Date() uses "GMT" if not given directly?

Comment: The default of `as.Date` is UTC. Read `?as.Date`

Answer (score 4):

the problem is the timezone

try your timezone (probably not GMT)

```
test$date2 <- as.Date(test$posixdate, "GMT")
```

and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557028/date-conversion-from-posixct-to-date-in-r) post

Comment: Thank you! Although I was searching for a similar post I did not find it.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `lubridate` package. It works for me.

```
library(lubridate)

as.Date(ymd_hms(test$posixdate))

[1] "2013-05-01" "2013-05-01" "2013-05-01" "2013-05-01"
```