# Unexpected date when converting POSIXct date-time to Date - timezone issue?

Tags: r, date, datetime, timezone, posixct

When I try to coerce a `POSIXct` date-time to a `Date` using `as.Date`, it seems to return wrong date.

I suspect it has got something to do with the time zone. I tried the `tz` argument in `as.Date`, but it didn't give the expected date.

```
# POSIXct returns day of month 24  
data$Time[3]
# [1] "2020-03-24 00:02:00 IST"

class(data$Time[3])
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

# coerce to Date, returns 23 
as.Date(data$Time[3])
# [1] "2020-03-23"

# try the time zone argument, without luck
as.Date(data$Time[3], tz = "IST")
# [1] "2020-03-23"
# Warning message:
# In as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz = tz) : unknown timezone 'IST' 

Sys.timezone()
# [1] "Asia/Calcutta"
```

Any ideas what may be going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the setup in the Note at the end we can use any of these:

```
# same date as print(x) shows
as.Date(as.character(x))
## [1] "2020-03-24"

# use the time zone stored in x (or system time zone if that is "")
as.Date(x, tz = attr(x, "tzone"))
## [1] "2020-03-24"

# use system time zone
as.Date(x, tz = "")
## [1] "2020-03-24"

# use system time zone
as.Date(x, tz = Sys.timezone())
## [1] "2020-03-24"

# use indicated time zone
as.Date(x, tz = "Asia/Calcutta")
## [1] "2020-03-24"
```

### Note

We have assumed this setup.

```
Sys.setenv(TZ = "Asia/Calcutta")
x <- structure(1584988320, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")

R.version.string
## [1] "R version 4.0.2 Patched (2020-06-24 r78745)"
```

Comment: Thanks! The output is `structure(1584988320, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")` and yes the idiom that you posted seems to work: `as.Date(data$Time[3], tz = "Asia/Calcutta")`

Comment: This works well too! `as.Date(x, tz = attr(x, "tzone"))` Many thanks!

Comment: `Sys.timezone()` gave `[1] "Asia/Calcutta"` Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The first idiom `as.Date(x, tz = check_tzones(x))` seems to be failing.  `check_tzones(data$Time[3])` gives `NULL`

Comment: Yes, I couldn't get that one to work either. I have revised the answer to only include the ones that worked and to add a Note showing how to reproduce the input.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks for a nice answer. Would you mind adding relevant alternatives to this post: [Date conversion from POSIXct to Date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16557028/date-conversion-from-posixct-to-date-in-r), which I think is a canonical post for a closely related topic. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

The clue is in the warning message.  `as.Date()` doesn't know how to interpret `IST` as a timezone and so defaults to `UTC`.  Assuming that `IST` is *Indian* Standard Time (rather than *Irish* Standard time) and that IST is UTC+5:30, `as.Date()` is giving the expected result, even if it is incorrect for your purposes.

Providing a date with a timezone expressed as an offset from UTC gives the desired result.

```
as.Date("2020-03-24 00:02:00 UTC+5:30")
[1] "2020-03-24"
```

Comment: Thank you! It is indeed Indian and not Irish! :)  I assumed "IST" would do since the first posixCT output itself had an IST in there! Apparently not! Is there a list of which time zone abbreviations are acceptable? I trawled through the help docs but could not find one.

Comment: Now the problem is I already have a data frame `data` with those date values like `2020-03-24 00:02:00 IST` stored in `data$time` Do I have to string manipulate those to get the UTC+5:30 in there? Or....?  Is the mistake at the spot where I created the data frame using `data$Time<-as.POSIXct(data$Time,format="%m-%d-%y %I:%M %p")` Should I be doing this differently so that the timezone gets encoded right there?